# Google Play Games: reset achievements of a regular user

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is there any trick to reset the currently authenticated user achievements? (not a tester, just a normal player, so this [Management API method](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/achievements/reset) won't do)

This kind of need might seem weird, but it's not so uncommon for players to want to start from scratch.

Google documentation does not mention this possibility.

Comment: just a question, the method you mentioned doesn't work for an error or simply it executes without doing anything?

Comment: I have not tried it as the doc explicitly mentions that `This method is only accessible to whitelisted tester accounts for your application.`